# How do we treat continuous variables inside summations?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, graphing-functions

I've been getting confused everytime we're graphing a summation with a continuous variable inside. For example, say I want to graph this equation with respect to $f$ ($y$ vertical, $f$ horizontal)

$$ y = 5\sum_{k=0}^\infty \operatorname{sinc}^2 \left(\frac k2 \right) \delta(f-k) $$

How do I account for the continuous variabality of $f$ inside? I know this maps to a comb function multiplied by varying constants, but I don't get how f is dealt with. Doesn't it vary continously with $k$?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! When you have a minute, please take the [tour of the site](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and look at [how to format mathematics here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on Math SE. Also, I suggest that you bookmark this [very useful MathJax page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for quick reference. Cheers!

Comment: I suggest you type out the equation (using MathJax, if possible) and only include pictures only if it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Tralala Done. I hope this makes things clearer.

Comment: Hmm, your summation variable $i$ is not mentioned at all in the expression you're summing over ... should it have been $k$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh sorry, yes it should have been k. Wrote I by mistake because it was in the MathJax tutorial.

Comment: Also is the $\delta$ a _Dirac_ delta? In that case what you get is not even a function but a distribution.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes its an impulse function. I'm asking the question mostly because I get confused when graphing continuous functions within summations. It's a bit like dealing with two variables, except one is discrete and one is continuous. I'm not sure if the direc delta function is a bad choice for this question.

Comment: @MZein: I'm not even sure what you mean by that. Do you have any concept about "graphing a summation" when there is no other variable than the summation variable involved? Do you have the same problem if you think about something with no $\delta$ in it, such as $$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Okay so after thinking through your example and revising some of my direc delta knowledge I've figured it out. For example with $$ y= \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k $$ I will have a value of y evaluated for each value of x, calculated through the summation, leading to a continuous graph. What was originally confusing me was my supposition that $\delta(f)$ would vary according to f while it simply means an impulse at 0 and nothing otherwise. Took asking the question and some give and take for me to correct my misunderstandings. Thanks for the help.